# How to calculate the limit $\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{k=1}^n\sqrt{n^4+k}\sin(\frac{2k\pi }{n})$? Is it a Riemann sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

I just came across this limit and I suppose it can be computed using a Riemann sum but I can't get it right.
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{k=1}^n\sqrt{n^4+k}\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi }{n}\right)$$
Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem to me that could be solved by Riemann sums...

Comment: I found it the integral calculus chapter of a book.

Comment: @user528021 Can you please check the question again to ensure there is no typo?

Comment: @Jaideep Khare There is no typo. There's also no context, the "I found it the integral calculus chapter of a book" is only in a comment, not in the question, and I'm not told why that could be interesting for anybody else.

Comment: @Netchaiev: it definitely *can* be solved by Riemann sums. The non-trivial part is just to manage cancellations.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: At least not directly... since you need another series to use a Riemann sum... But I enjoyed your solution and upvoted for you! :)

Comment: @user528021,I am just curious about of which book the integral calculus chapter give out the problem?

Comment: It's from a university admission book. They used to have it online but their site seems to be down at the moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is slightly tricky. You may notice that for any $k\in[1,n]$ the term $\sqrt{n^4+k}$ is considerably larger than $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$, but there is a massive cancellation due to the fact that $\sin(2\pi x)$ is positive for $x\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and negative for $x\in\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$. So, better to perform some reindexing via $k\mapsto n-k$:
$$ S_n=\sum_{k=1}\sqrt{n^4+k}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)=\sum_{k\leq n/2}\left(\sqrt{n^4+k}-\sqrt{n^4+n-k}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) .\tag{1}$$
Now we may notice that $\sqrt{n^4+k}-\sqrt{n^4+n-k}$ is negative and it equals
$$ \frac{2k-n}{\sqrt{n^4+k}+\sqrt{n^4+n-k}}\approx \frac{2k-n}{2n^2} \tag{2}$$
where by Riemann sums
$$ \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k\leq \frac{n}{2}}\left(2\frac{k}{n}-1\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\to \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1/2}(2x-1)\sin(2\pi x)\,dx =  \color{red}{-\frac{1}{4\pi}}.\tag{3}$$
I leave to you to make this argument rigorous, i.e. to prove that we are allowed to replace the LHS of $(2)$ with the RHS.

Comment: You . Are . Genius .

Comment: I just wanted to say that numerically $-1/4\pi$ makes more sense. +1

Comment: @Fabian: of course, I missed a factor $2$ before, now fixed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use $$\sqrt{n^4+k}=n^2\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^4}}=n^2+\frac12\frac{k}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{k^2}{n^6}\right)$$ and $$\sum _{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi }{n}\right)=0?$$

Comment: @ProfessorVector: that's a viable way too, sure. I just found it more natural to exploit symmetry directly.

Comment: Can you explain the indexing on $\sum_{k\le n/2}$? Is that equivalent to $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$? (I know the floor delimiters are unnecessary but I threw them in just to be clear.) I’m guessing that because there’s a ultimately a limit to be taken, the initial value for the index (i.e., whether $k$ starts at $0$ or $1$) is irrelevant. Yes?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: if $n$ is even the contribution given by $k=n/2$ is zero, so using $\leq n/2$ or $\leq\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ is exactly the same.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio And the initial value?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: the contribution provided by $k=0$ is also zero.